# session id extraction from a curl response

Tags: php, session, curl

I got the curl response as following format.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 13 Nov 2014 05:34:03 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu) Set-Cookie: sid=o58lq30rgnqsep720kbje8cap5; path=/ Cache-Control: no-cache Allow: POST Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 {"Response":{"reasonCode":"0","reasonText":"The consumer was successfully logged in with a session cookie","reasonImageURL":"","satn":"213456","rrn":"1415856843"}}
```

I want to get the session id to store it. I tried some links to solve it but nothing worked. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
preg_match('/SID=(\w+)/', $response['body'], $matches);
$sid = $matches[1]; //sid
```

Comment: This won't work.first, it won't match OP's string becasue you didn't use the `i` flag.secondly, you have to use `\w+` instead of `.+` else it'll capture everything(up until a new line) after the `sid=` part.

Comment: Hi Himal, that's correct. I added \w+ instead of .+ and it worked.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For correct solution of this you should parse HTTP response correctly...

```
$response = "";
list($headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
$raw_headers = explode("\r\n", $headers);
array_shift($raw_headers); // exclude first row 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
$headers = array();
foreach($raw_headers as $header) {
  list($key, $value) = explode(": ", $header, 2);
  $headers[strtoupper($key)] = $value;
}
$cookie = $headers['SET-COOKIE'];
preg_match('/sid=([a-f\d])/i', $cookie, $matches);
if ($matches) {
  $session_id = $matches[1];
}
```